# How to adjust angle of line of a path so that it is parallel to another line in the same path

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have the following 4 sided path:

[image]

I would like line A to be parallel to line B.

Is there a clever hotkey that allows me to snap the line angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, you can **Alt-Drag** copy your figure and move down till a vertex snaps, then **Direct Select** one vert and move it till it snaps... like so:

[image]

Achieves much the same idea as @LeoNas's method but without a pathfinder boolean.

Answer (score 2):

No. You would have to manually fix it:

- hit <kbd>A</kbd> and drag the left corner of A until in touches the left corner of B
- hit <kbd>A</kbd> and do the same for the right corner of A
- hit <kbd>A</kbd> and click in the middle of B, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> so the entire A segment starts moving up. Keep going until you get it in the right position

There are different ways to approach this, but nothing automatic as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

My method:

Duplicate it using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> until the top left anchor aligns to bottom left anchor. You can enable the Outline View <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for a better alignment. Or just unfill the duplicated path.

Use the Pathfinder>>MinusFront or Shape Builder Tool holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to subtract the unwanted parts.

See the image below:

[image]